# Minimum One to Many in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, data-processing

Given an input CSV file as follows, using Python, how to get the 2 output CSV below?

Input CSV file Example:

```
Book, Author
Book 30,“Author X”
Book 27,“Author F”
Book 17,”Author Y, Author Z”
Book 1,“Author X, Author Y, Author Z”
Book 5,”Author Y, Author G”
```

Output 1 CSV file shall represent the minimal number of books that is linked to all authors, so in the example case it would be:

```
Book
Book 1
Book 27
Book 5
```

Output 2 CSV file shall list each of the authors and which book of the minimal list is linked to him. So in the example case it would be:

```
Book, Author
Book 1,Author X
Book 1,Author Y
Book 1,Author Z
Book 27,Author F
Book 5,Author G
```

Comment: are these particularly big files? Are there any constraints on how this should be built? Do you have any code or errors to share?

Comment: @Richard the input file has around 44K rows. no constraints on how this should be built other than being done in Python and shall finish in considerable time. and no code or errors to share

Comment: Good form is to attempt a solution first - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Richard I'm here more for the idea than the actual code :)